# Is Baron and Kenny method for mediation now outdated?

Tags: mediation

Is Baron and Kenny method for mediation now outdated? This is because I got a comment from reviewer saying asking me to refer to Rucker, D.D., Preacher, K.J., Tormala, Z.L. & Petty, R.E. (2011). Mediation analysis in social psychology: Current practices and new recommendations.