# Mediation. IV - DV (Negative Beta) IV - MV -DV (Positive Beta )

Tags: regression, mediation

STEP 1: [image: Taking Prevention focus as Independent variable and Perceived behavioural control as Mediating variable]The relationship between IV (Prevention Focus) & MV (Perceived behavioural control) is significant (0.010) Beta -0.173

STEP 2: [image: Taking Prevention focus as Independent variable and Entrepreneurial intention as dependent variable]The relationship between IV (Prevention focus) & DV (Entrepreneurial intention) is significant (0.03) but with negative Beta value. -0.146

STEP 3: Introducing Mediating variable in direct effect model 
When MV ( Perceived behavioural control is introduced between IV
(Prevention Focus) & DV (Entrepreneurial intention)  the relationship between IV & DV remains negative and  becomes insignificant.However, now the beta value of Perceived behavioural control is positive and significant which I interpreted as full mediation [image]

STEP 4: Relation between Mediating variable BC and Dependent Variable Entrepreneurial intention. [image]
I am following Baron & Kenny approach to find mediation.

How do I interpret this ?

Comment: What do you mean *"When MV is introduced between IV & DV"* -  a regression model knows nothing about "in between". What exactly are the models you fitted in each step ?

Comment: Hi Robert I have posted screen shots of the results so as to make my questions clear.

Comment: Rather than just post SPSS output, it would be better if you describe what the variables are, in each model. I don't like the Baron/Kenny approach - I would much prefer a path analysis approach. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112575/is-baron-and-kenny-method-for-mediation-now-outdated) is some info about B/K and it's limitations.

Comment: IV is Prevention Focus , DV is Entrepreneurial intention , Mediator is Perceived behavioural control.

Comment: The Baron-Kenny approach requires a regression of the dependent variable on the presumed mediator. You don't seem to have done that.  It us unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I have edited the post.Read: Alt in the output as Entrepreneurial intention.

Comment: Note that, these days, there are better approaches to mediation analysis than B and K.

Comment: @RobertLong I've done the regression of dependent variable on presumed mediator. Please,relook .

Comment: @PeterFlom I've used Hayes and Preacher, Process 3 plugin in  SPSS. However,I am confused with the interpretation. Please, share if you have a document on how mediation is analysed in H & P if one of the interval is negative.

Comment: Look at the link that @RobertLong provided

Comment: So what is the problem ? I don't see any change in sign of any coefficient between these regressions (and even if it did, it should not be a problem). It appears that you have found evidence that the effect is indeed mediated.

Comment: Problem is how can a negative direct relationship become positive just because of a mediator ? In terms of moderation I can understand that under XYZ context the relationship is positive. The theory says the direct relationship is positive I be got it to be negative but positive when mediated.

Comment: The coefficient for PVF is negative throughout, and the coefficient for BC is positive throughout. Nothing has changed sign as far as I can see (but it woundn't surprise me if it did, because that is exactly what *can* happen when you add a mediator into a regression)